# using componentWillUnmount in context of next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to run a method on componentWillUnmount(i'm using the next js framework).The issue is that the componentWillUnmount method does not fire. However componentDidMount is working fine.

```
 class TeamMember extends Component {
          constructor(props)
          {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              teamMember: this.props.teamMember,
              startDate: null,

            }
          }
       static async getInitialProps ( context ) {

            const { slug } = context.query;
            const res = await fetch(``);
            const teamMember = await res.json();
            return {
              teamMember:teamMember
            }

          }
        async componentDidMount()
        {
        this.setState({
          startDate: Date.now()
        })
        Tracker.pushObjectToStorage('profilesViewed',{
          title:this.state.teamMember[0].title.rendered,
          id:this.state.teamMember[0].id
        })
      }
      async componentWillUnmount(props)
      {
        alert("ddffff");
        console.log("ddsds");
      }
    }
```

this is my code for the page. when you leave the page I want the componentWillUnmount to fire. i've put an alert there for test purposes.

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Answer (score 3):

This is expected and intended behavior of Nextjs routing. For more information, you can check this issue: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2819.

When you go to another page, no unmounting of components occurs, but instead, a whole new page is rendered.

This is the same behaviour as if you were refreshing (or landing for the first time) on a page. A React component will not `unmount` when you hit `F5` on a page, because it is not unmounting, the page is simply refreshing.